# Why does the color not show in my css? If I comment out the footer a color it does appear but the rest of the text look like garbage

Tags: html, css

```
<footer id="footer">
        <div id="footerRight">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="currentbottomnav" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="footerLeft">
            <p>Follow us</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
            <p>.........................</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS--------------------------------------------------

```
footer {
color:white;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height: auto; 
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
padding: 15px;
box-sizing: border-box;/*Removes the extra width on the box*/
border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 5%;

}

footer #footerLeft a{
    font-size:25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
footer #footerRight a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: whitesmoke;
    margin:10px;
}

.currentbottomnav {
    color: aqua; 
}


footer ul {
    list-style: none;

}

footer li {
    display:inline-block;
}

footer #footerRight a:hover{
    color: rgb(90 90 90);
    font-weight: 300;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
footer #footerLeft a:hover{
    color: rgb(90 90 90);
    font-weight: 300;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#footerRight{
    float:right;

}
#footerLeft{
    float: left;    
}
```

I am talking about the "footer #footerRight a{... }", one. If I comment out the whitesmoke there,  the color aqua pops up for the first element as it intended (this is what I want) but the rest of the elements are no longer pretty because they are no longer customized with whitesmoke.

I am trying to change the color of my quick links in the footer as well as the header links. I got the ones for header link to work but now when I try to do the ones for footer it doesn't work. I am using a class to change the colors.

Comment: <ul>
                    <li><a class="currentbottomnav" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

Comment: To help us help you you'll need to provide us with as much of the code that is as possible in your question (not in the comments). You don't need to provide the entire page just that that is relevant. The code you have provided as a comment does not contain the footer #footerLeft elements so we would be unable to provide an accurate solution from that.

Comment: @UntitledGraphic Does this help? Also, .currentbottomnav {} to replace the whitesmoke.

Comment: that is just what is needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aqua colour is not showing up because the you are using IDs in your CSS. IDs take precedent over any standard use of a class name.

so `.currentbottomnav` is being overridden by `footer #footerRight a`

The quick fix to your problem would be to change to `footer #footerRight .currentbottomnav`.

However the crux of your problem lies with the use of IDs to hook styles on. Instead create a class for each element and use those instead. IDs are great for providing unique hooks for javascript etc to make use of, but in CSS they are best avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: For javascript only IDs work? 
I should only be using Classes for CSS and ID's to work on Javascript. I used id's for divs, is that wrong?

Comment: Both IDs and classes can work in javascript. It is definitely not wrong to reference classes but IDs provide a unique reference as they should only be used once on each page.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your code, People from here could help you in a better way.
There you have a code that could help you to understand CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
footer{
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
footer a{
color: yellow;
}
footer p.blackcolor div.blackcolor{
    color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<footer>
  <p>Posted by: Hege Refsnes</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">someone@example.com</a>.</p>
<p class="blackcolor">Posted by: Hege Refsnes</p>
<div class="blackcolor">Posted by: Hege Refsnes</div>
</footer>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The footer tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```